# Regular expression to capture n lines of text between two regex patterns

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

Need help with a regular expression to grab exactly n lines of text between two regex matches. For example, I need 17 lines of text and I used the example below, which does not work. I

Please see sample code below:

```
import re
match_string = re.search(r'^.*MDC_IDC_RAW_MARKER((.*?\r?\n){17})Stored_EGM_Trigger.*\n'), t, re.DOTALL).group()
value1 = re.search(r'value="(\d+)"', match_string).group(1)
value2 = re.search(r'value="(\d+\.\d+)"', match_string).group(1)
print(match_string)
print(value1)
print(value2)
```

I added a sample string to here, because SO does not allow long code string:
https://hastebin.com/aqowusijuc.xml

Comment: Save yourself days of frustrating failure by using Python [XML Processing modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html) instead of a Regex.

Comment: Well, there is some code that already uses lxml etree functionality, but I figured that maybe I could get away with some one liner regex

Comment: I primarily wanted to know how to enforce reading something like 17 lines between two matches as I am getting some false positives.

Comment: I got the following regex for now: r'(.*MDC_IDC_DEVICE_MARKER(.*\n){17}.*Stored_EGM_Trigger\"/>)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting false positives because you are using the re.DOTALL flag, which allows the `.` character to match newline characters. That is, when you are matching `((.*?\r?\n){17})`, the `.` could eat up many extra newline characters just to satisfy your required count of 17. You also now realize that the `\r` is superfluous. Also, starting your regex with `^.*?` is superfluous because you are forcing the search to start from the beginning but then saying that the search engine should skip as many characters as necessary to find `MDC_IDC_RAW_MARKER`. So, a simplified and correct regex would be:

```
match_string = re.search(r'MDC_IDC_RAW_MARKER.*\n((.*\n){17})Stored_EGM_Trigger.*\n', t)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dkcrNV/2/)